jebrans-fleet failed to detect the .git folder
Strangely, fleet doesn't recognize git folders .
I konw how deal this in vscode.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#_why-is-vs-code-warning-me-that-the-git-repository-is-potentially-unsafe
So, how setting to dectect the  .git folder?

You have to go to settings json file:

and change the following key (so that it stops including the git):
 "files.exclude": [".DS_Store", ".git"]


thanks . This setting just show git folder in Files list . The GIt infomation  that behind peojection name at  top menu bar  is still exist red warning
